# How can a closure be stored in a newtype in Rust?

Tags: rust, closures, newtype

I am trying to wrap an external type using my own type, as outlined in the linked [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3b281425db337989077e23b92f1d40ee).

The external type stores a closure on initialization:

```rust
struct ExternalType<P> {
    predicate: P,
}

impl<P> ExternalType<P>
where
    P: FnMut(u8) -> bool,
{
    fn new(predicate: P) -> Self {
        ExternalType { predicate }
    }
}
```

My "newtype" uses this `ExternalType` (without exposing it), but uses a different closure, e.g., a different argument type, which is converted internally:

```rust
struct MyType<P> {
    ext: ExternalType<P>,
}

impl<P> MyType<P>
where
    P: FnMut(u8) -> bool,
{
    fn new<Q>(user_predicate: Q) -> Self
    where
        Q: FnMut(u32) -> bool,
    {
        // This fails to compile since the closure is not of type `P`.
        let f: P = move |num| user_predicate(num as u32);
        Self {
            ext: ExternalType::new(f),
        }
    }
}
```

Without changing the signature of my `user_predicate` (the actual code is a bit more intricate), is there any way of storing this closure?

I know that every closure has its own type and therefore the implemented closure does not match the given type `Q`, but on the other hand I have no idea on how to implement or annotate this fact in my type and especially not in the `impl` block.

I've seen the [question regarding on how to store a closure in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68066875/how-to-store-a-closure-inside-rust-struct) but it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Use the `struct MyType(Box<dyn FnMut(u8) -> bool>);` adapted from the 2nd option on the answer on [How to store a closure inside Rust struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68066875/how-to-store-a-closure-inside-rust-struct)

Comment: No, as mentioned in the last sentence of my question I've already checked this. The problem I seem to have is that I need to annotate my `impl` block with a type that is different (?) than the closure I provide in the code.

EDIT: Is there no way to use generics for that? I'd try not to use trait objects since this is also not always possible.

Comment: There is no way to convert arbitrary type `Q` to arbitrary other type `P` even if they implement the same trait.

Comment: `Box<..>` doesn't really help me here since then rust complains that the closure needs to be `'static` to be stored. So there is also no other way to annotate this implementation?

Comment: Ah yes, non `'static` lifetimes have to be explicitly named in struct definitions, `struct MyType<'a>(Box<dyn FnMut(u8) -> bool + 'a>);` and according changes across the example.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, but then that failed in my "real word code" since I cannot really give a lifetime to the user predicate, which I'd expect to be moved into the predicate and then into the `Box` (if that is the correct way to explain what I'd hope would happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by instead of returning `Self`, return an `impl` type [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5c5d939036d33af862a7d862fca60998)

```rs
fn new<Q>(mut user_predicate: Q) -> MyType<impl FnMut(u8) -> bool>
where
    Q: FnMut(u32) -> bool,
{
    let f = move |num| user_predicate(num as u32);
    MyType {
        ext: ExternalType::new(f),
    }
}
```

## Future rust

This will be more ergonomic later with [type alias impl trait](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063). This will let you give the closure a name:

```rs
type P<Q> = impl FnMut(u8) -> bool;
```

which you can then use as `MyType`'s generic:

```rs
impl<Q> MyType<P<Q>>
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bb27ced37a4f7756bcb59feadbcd2e56)

Comment: Using `impl` solves this problem. Maybe I can update the playground with a more intricate example where I use the type recursively, but then the problem is effectively that I am trying to use generics for two different closure types, so in the end the rust compiler seems to be correct to forbid this. It is just not "immediately visible" that this is a problem.