# In Rust, what is the most idiomatic way to pass an function that performs `==` and returns i32?

Tags: rust

Here is a Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/q9bsnMn7q

And here is what I am trying to solve:

```rust
use std::ops::{Add, Sub};

fn f(a: i32, b: i32, binop: &dyn Fn(i32, i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
    binop(a, b) as i32
}

fn main() {

    // Examples using Sub::sub and Add::add
    println!("{}", f(1, 2, &Add::add));
    println!("{}", f(1, 2, &Sub::sub));

    // This works (but seems non-idiomatic) compared to above
    let eq1 = |a, b| if a == b {1} else {0};
    let eq2 = |a, b| (a == b).into();

    println!("{}", f(1, 2, &eq1));
    println!("{}", f(1, 2, &eq2));

    // Is there something like this?
    // println!("{}", f(1, 2, &PartialEq::eq as i32));
}
```

Comment: `a == b` returns `bool`, not `i32`, and `Eq::eq` does not exist (perhaps you meant `PartialEq::eq()`).

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre] so that it is clear what you are trying to do. If it does not compile, include the full error message _verbatim_ from Cargo.

Comment: Unless there is something specific about this question, this is a duplicate of [How do you pass a Rust function as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390665/how-do-you-pass-a-rust-function-as-a-parameter). Please [edit] the question if the answers within do not answer what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe you want to turn the return type of the closure into a generic type parameter, so you can pass in `PartialEq::eq`? If you still want to return `i32` from the wrapping function, you may need `T: Into<i32>` or similar. (It's hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve with the information given.)

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to the operator functions in `std::ops::{Add, Sub}` for the `==` operator is [`std::cmp::PartialEq::eq()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#tymethod.eq).

You might be confused that the `std::cmp::Eq` trait does not have an `eq()` function as well, this is because it behaves more as a marker trait indicating that (for a particular type) the `==` operator is [reflexive, symmetric, and transitive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html). Objects that implement the `Eq` trait still use `std::cmp::PartialEq::eq()` for the `==` operator.