# How do I move mutable state into a closure?

Tags: rust

Closures have some data in their state, but how do I make it mutable? For example, I want a counter closure which returns the incremented value each time, but it doesn't work. How do I make it work?

```
fn counter() -> Box<Fn() -> i32> {
    let mut c: i32 = 0;
    Box::new(move || {
        c += 1;
        c
    })
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = counter();
    let mut b = counter();
    println!("{:?}", [a(), a(), a(), b(), b(), a()]);
}
```

Error (and warning) I'm getting:

```
error: cannot assign to captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
        c += 1;
        ^~~~~~
help: consider changing this closure to take self by mutable reference
    Box::new(move || {
        c += 1;
        c
    })
```

I expect it to output something like `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4]`.

Comment: I don't know your goal exactly, but you might want to use the Iterator trait on a new struct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the error message says:

> cannot assign to captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure

Instead, you want a [`FnMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) closure:

```rust
// In modern Rust, prefer returning `impl FnMut() -> i32`
fn counter() -> Box<dyn FnMut() -> i32> {
    let mut c = 0;
    Box::new(move || {
        c += 1;
        c
    })
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = counter();
    let mut b = counter();

    let result = [a(), a(), a(), b(), b(), a()];
    println!("{:?}", result);

    assert_eq!([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4], result);
}
```

As the [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) docs say:

> The version of the call operator that takes a mutable receiver.

This allows the closure to mutate the contained state.

Incidentally, the explicit type for `c` is not needed.

---

> What confuses me, is that `pub trait Fn<Args>: FnMut<Args>`. Doesn't it mean that `Fn` (what I used) should support behaviour of `FnMut`?

Perhaps [When does a closure implement Fn, FnMut and FnOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30177395/155423) can help provide some background information. This is an aspect I get intuitively, but haven't figured out how best to communicate. This section from [Finding Closure in Rust](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/05/finding-closure-in-rust/) also seems relevant:

> At a high-level `self` gives implementers (i.e. the types users define to implement the trait) the most flexibility, with `&mut self` next and `&self` the least flexible. Conversely, `&self` gives consumers of the trait (i.e. functions with generics bounded by the trait) the most flexibility, and `self` the least.

In short, that trait definition says that any `Fn` closure can be **used where a `FnMut` closure is expected**. This makes some sense, as we can ignore the mutability available to the `FnMut`. You cannot go the other way - you cannot make an immutable reference into a mutable one.

Comment: "any FnMut closure can be used as a Fn closure" other way around, yes?

Comment: @Ry- it's all about which way you look at it from. I mention the trait **definition**, but you are looking at it from the trait **instantiation**. I'll see if I can clean up the wording.