# Passing a closure that modifies its environment to a function in Rust

Tags: closures, rust, immutability, traits

I have a closure that captures and modifies its environment. I want to pass this closure to a function that accepts closures:

```
fn main() {
    let mut integer = 5;
    let mut closure_variable = || -> i32 {
        integer += 1;
        integer
    };
    execute_closure(&mut closure_variable);
}

fn execute_closure(closure_argument: &mut Fn() -> i32) {
    let result = closure_argument();
    println!("Result of closure: {}", result);
}
```

Because the closure modifies its environment, this fails:

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnMut`
 --> src/main.rs:3:32
  |
3 |       let mut closure_variable = || -> i32 {
  |  ________________________________^
4 | |         integer += 1;
5 | |         integer
6 | |     };
  | |_____^
7 |       execute_closure(&mut closure_variable);
  |                       --------------------- the requirement to implement `Fn` derives from here
  |
note: closure is `FnMut` because it mutates the variable `integer` here
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |         integer += 1;
  |         ^^^^^^^
```

As I understand from [When does a closure implement Fn, FnMut and FnOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395), this means that my closure actually is expanded to a struct that implements the trait `FnMut`. This trait is mutable, meaning calling the function changes the (implicit) object. I think this correct, because the variable `integer` should be modified after calling `execute_closure()`.

How do I convince the compiler this is okay and that I actually want to call a `FnMut` function? Or is there something fundamentally wrong with how I use Rust in this example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### If you can change the function that accepts the closure...

Accept a `FnMut` instead of a `Fn`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut integer = 5;
    execute_closure(|| {
        integer += 1;
        integer
    });
}

fn execute_closure<F>(mut closure_argument: F)
where
    F: FnMut() -> i32,
{
    let result = closure_argument();
    println!("Result of closure: {}", result);
}
```

#### If you can not change the function that accepts the closure...

Use *interior mutability* provided by types like [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) or [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html):

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let integer = Cell::new(5);
    execute_closure(|| {
        integer.set(integer.get() + 1);
        integer.get()
    });
}

fn execute_closure<F>(closure_argument: F)
where
    F: Fn() -> i32,
{
    let result = closure_argument();
    println!("Result of closure: {}", result);
}
```

---

> Or is there something fundamentally wrong with how I use Rust in this example?

Perhaps. An argument of type `&mut Fn() -> i32` cannot mutate the variables it has closed over, so the error message makes sense to me.

It's *kind* of similar to the type `&mut &u8` — you could alter the outer reference to point to another immutable reference, but you cannot "ignore" the inner immutability and change the numeric value.

Aside:

The original code uses *dynamic dispatch* because there is a *trait object* that provides indirection. In many cases you'd see this version that I posted above, which uses static dispatch and can be *monomorphized*. I've also inlined the closure as that's the normal syntax.

Here's the original version with just enough changes to work:

```
fn main() {
    let mut integer = 5;
    let mut closure_variable = || -> i32 {
        integer += 1;
        integer
    };
    execute_closure(&mut closure_variable);
}

fn execute_closure(closure_argument: &mut FnMut() -> i32) {
    let result = closure_argument();
    println!("Result of closure: {}", result);
}
```

Comment: Now that I see your answer I feel stupid I never realised that Fn in the function syntax is the name of the Trait it should implement. Thanks!
As for the inlined closure, I believe that naming a variable is documenting it. An inlined closure is worse than a magic number.

Comment: @Johan I think you mean *I feel like I know more today than I did yesterday* ^_^.