# How to implement "take while, but at most N characters" in nom?

Tags: rust, nom

How can I give nom's [`take_while`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/bytes/complete/fn.take_while.html) an upper limit on the number of characters it should match? I want to take characters according to a certain condition, but at most `N`.

Since this will be a very performance critical part of the parser, I'd like to avoid using a bunch of individual [`take(1usize)`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/bytes/complete/fn.take.html). Partly, because it feels awkward having to deal with single element slices one-by-one, but also because the compiler probably cannot know at compile time that they must have a size of 1, i.e., it will likely have to generate bound checks or size assertions, right?

Conceptually, a `take_while` with an upper limit would feel more appropriate. I was hoping I can do the counting with a mutable loop variable myself like so:

```rust
let mut i = 0;

let (input, _) = take_while(|c| {
    i += 1;
    c >= 0x80 && i < 9
})(input)?;
```

In fact, I could even extract the necessary information in the closure, which most like should result in a very efficient code generation. (The goal is to implement a certain kind of VarInt LSB encoding, i.e., I could update a local mutable variable `x = x + (if last_byte { c } else { c & 0x7f }) << 7`.)

Unfortunately `take_while` seems to allow only `Fn` and not `FnMut` which probably means this is impossible (why the limitation?). What else could I do to implement that nicely?

Comment: Maybe the solution is to encode the position of the token you want to apply your condition on directly in the token, with an `enumerate`-like transformation of your input?

Comment: Wouldn't [`take_while_m_n`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/bytes/complete/fn.take_while_m_n.html) fit your use case?

Comment: @SirDarius Indeed, I missed `take_while_m_n`, but I don't think it would solve the use case, because the condition in the last byte actually doesn't have to be true! Apparently `take_while_m_n` requires the condition to be satisfied over `m <= len <= n`. Also since I have to do the same bit masking again to compute the actual varint, I would think doing it all in one loop is faster than having to loop over the returned buffer again, doing similar work twice. But that requires benchmarking of course.

Comment: Well actually I could consume the last byte manually separately, but its very awkward compared to `FnMut` closure solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) to make your closure have interior mutability. Then it can have mutable state, but still implement `Fn`:

```
let i = Cell::new(0);

let (input, _) = take_while(|c| {
    i.set(i.get() + 1);
    c > 0x80 && i.get() < 9
})(input)?;
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that trick ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38677845/1804173)), this seems to do the job well. I take it, `Cell` is a zero-cost abstraction (at least this [comment](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-refcell-a-zero-cost-abstraction/61888/9) says so), and I don't have to worry about bypassing `Fn` here? For the curious: [resulting varint parser implementation](https://github.com/bluenote10/RustExperiments/blob/4e0d9dfa3a3922894fa169cf32cdcab05c1bb982/SerdeChecks/src/custom_file_format/deserialize.rs#L8-L31).

Comment: @bluenote10 `Cell` can inhibit certain optimizations by permitting aliased modification, but that won't matter most of the time, and it shouldn't have any effects other than that. Also, you're not bypassing `Fn` here- you're still fulfilling the required contract, even if it feels weird.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nom-function [`take_while_m_n`](https://docs.rs/nom/7.1.1/nom/bytes/complete/fn.take_while_m_n.html):

```rust
const N: usize = ...

fn take_native(input: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], &[u8]> {
    take_while_m_n(0, N, |c| c > 0x80)(input)
}
```

However, with quick benchmark it seems to be remarkably slower than the [`Cell` -answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71894963/499839) (or benchmark optimizes wrongly, since the `Cell` -version takes only 1ns/iter compared to 13ns/iter for the take_while_m_n).

```
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

use std::cell::Cell;

use nom::{
    bytes::complete::{take_while, take_while_m_n},
    IResult,
};

fn take_cell(input: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], &[u8]> {
    let i = Cell::new(0);

    let (input, output) = take_while(|c| {
        i.set(i.get() + 1);
        c > 0x80 && i.get() < 5
    })(input)?;

    Ok((input, output))
}

fn take_native(input: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], &[u8]> {
    take_while_m_n(0, 4, |c| c > 0x80)(input)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    const INPUT: &[u8] = &[
        0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83,
        0x84, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84,
    ];

    #[bench]
    fn bench_cell(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
        assert_eq!(take_cell(INPUT).unwrap().1, &[0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84]);

        b.iter(|| take_cell(INPUT).unwrap());
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_native(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
        assert_eq!(take_native(INPUT).unwrap().1, &[0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84]);

        b.iter(|| take_native(INPUT).unwrap());
    }
}
```