# How can I pass around variables between handlers

Tags: rust, iron

I want to have a context-struct that is available in all handlers, but I am not able to get trough the compiler.

For an example, I want something like this

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate router;

use iron::prelude::*;
use router::Router;
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Context {
    cache: HashMap<String, String>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut context = Context { cache: HashMap::new(), };
    let mut router = Router::new();

    router.get("/", |request| index(request, context));

    Iron::new(router).http("localhost:80").unwrap();
}


fn index(_: &mut Request, context: Context) -> IronResult<Response> {
    Ok(Response::with((iron::status::Ok, "index")))
}
```

This won't compile with a lengthy error message

```
error: type mismatch resolving `for<'r, 'r, 'r> <[closure@src\main.rs:... context:_] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r mut iron::Request<'r, 'r>,)>>::Output == std::result::Result<iron::Response, iron::IronError>`:
 expected bound lifetime parameter ,
    found concrete lifetime [E0271]
src\main.rs:...     router.get("/", |request| index(request, context));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is almost incomprehensible here (there is a [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24680) for it!).

The problem is that the type of the closure is not being inferred. We can help the compiler annotating the type of `request`:

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate router;

use iron::prelude::*;
use router::Router;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[derive(Clone, Default)]
struct Context {
    cache: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, String>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let context = Context::default();
    let mut router = Router::new();

    let c = context.clone();
    router.get("/", move |request: &mut Request| index(request, &c), "index");

    Iron::new(router).http("localhost:8080").unwrap(); // port 80 is privileged
}

fn index(_: &mut Request, context: &Context) -> IronResult<Response> {
    Ok(Response::with((iron::status::Ok, "index")))
}
```

Note that I changed the type of `context` to `&Context` (otherwise, the closure would only [implements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30177395/5189607) `FnOnce`) and use `move` (the closure must have `'static` lifetime to implement [`Handler`](http://ironframework.io/doc/iron/middleware/trait.Handler.html)).

To make it possible to change `cache` in `index`, you will have to [change](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/choosing-your-guarantees.html) the type to `Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, String>>>` or similar.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Now I did not state this in my original problem, but I have more than one of these router.get-lines ( which is the point of using a router) and adding a second line like that ( router.get("/hi", move |...| hi(...)); ) will result in new compiler errors. error: capture of moved value: `context`

Comment: Again many thanks for this. There is a lot I do not understand here ( why do I need to clone everything, when the content of the struct will be the same, why do I need to 'move' my closure and what does that even mean, why are these derives at my struct ). I read the rust programming book/doc thing and now just realize that I don't really understood what they wrote there.

Comment: You can also use the [persistent](https://github.com/iron/persistent) crate for shared data instead of wrapping it in an Arc and Mutex.

Comment: if you guys get this error, change port 80 to 3000:

thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Error { repr: Os { code: 13, message: "Permission denied" } })', src/libcore/result.rs:906:4
@malbarbo could you edit to port 3000 so less people get this stupid little error? :)