# How do Rust closures work and how does it execute a closure?

Tags: multithreading, rust, closures

Does it create a new thread and then execute that anonymous function inside the new thread?

I noticed many ownership / borrowing restrictions when I'm working with a closure. For example, if I have `Fn()`, [I cannot pass a mutable variable inside the closure or it needs to be wrapped with a `Mutex`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7a9e0f376c5fcd2d4324b88918beceab&version=stable):

```
fn helloworld(f: &Fn(f64)) {
    f(42f64);
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut killer = 2;
    helloworld(&|n| {
        println!("{}", n);
        killer += 1;
    });
}
```

If a closure can be unsafe like that then something asynchronous or parallel is going on behind the scene and that's why Rust compiler doesn't let me to compile such code.

I might just be confused because I'm coming from a JavaScript / Python world and things are completely different there.

Comment: A closure is an anonymous function with variable capture, it is not multithreaded (unless you ask for it). Moreover, could you post the code you refer to, when you say "if I have `Fn()`, I cannot pass a mutable variable inside the closure or it needs to be wrapped with a `Mutex`"?

Comment: @Boiethios sure, just updated the question with a link.

Comment: You need to use `FnMut`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6c4a057153b0781a52b9171c5f2b2081&version=stable But I let someone with more knowledge to answer with detailed explanations.

Comment: @Boiethios that is correct, changing to FnMut or using a Mutex can solve the problem but my question is, why? If it is not a separate thread, why it should be even important to pass a Mutex?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are two layers to this question.

First, a closure in Rust is just an anonymously-defined type that implements one or more "callable" traits.  For example, this:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 6;
    let closure = |b| {
        println!("product is: {}", a * b);
    };
    closure(7);
}
```

is de-sugared into something similar to:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 6;
    let closure = {
        struct Closure<'a> {
            a: &'a i32,
        }
        impl<'a> Fn<(i32,)> for Closure<'a> {
            extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, (b,): (i32,)) {
                println!("product is: {}", (*self.a) * b);
            }
        }
        impl<'a> FnMut<(i32,)> for Closure<'a> {
            extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: (i32,)) {
                self.call(args)
            }
        }
        impl<'a> FnOnce<(i32,)> for Closure<'a> {
            type Output = ();
            extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (i32,)) {
                self.call(args)
            }
        }
        Closure {
            a: &a,
        }
    };
    FnOnce::call_once(closure, (7,));
}
```

> **Note**: the above code relies on unstable, internal details and will not work on a stable compiler.  It is provided for explanation only; you should **not** use this pattern yourself.

There's no threading involved, and nothing magical is happening.  They boil down to a regular function call with an extra initial "context" argument.

This brings us to the second layer, which is why your *specific* code doesn't work: *because you told the compiler to forbid it*.  One critical concern for callables is how the context is passed to the callable's code.  This is represented by the `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce` traits (which are explained in the answer to the question [When does a closure implement Fn, FnMut and FnOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395/when-does-a-closure-implement-fn-fnmut-and-fnonce)).  By taking `&Fn(f64)`, you've restricted yourself to only accepting closures which require immutable access to their context.

If you want a closure to be able to mutate its context, you need to use `FnMut` instead.  Or, if you only need to call a closure once, you can use `FnOnce` (although not as a trait object like you're doing in your example).

Comment: Oh wow, this is a nice and clear explanation. Thank you so much DK.