# Option::map(FnOnce) does not seem to accept FnOnce ...?

Tags: rust

I am a bit confused by `Option::map()`. The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#396) says it accepts a `FnOnce`.

If so, why do `a` and `b` cause compilations errors?

```
let mut v = 3;

let mut a: &FnOnce(u32) -> u32 = &|x: u32| { v = x; x };
let mut b: &FnMut(u32) -> u32 = &|x: u32| { x };
let mut c: &Fn(u32) -> u32 = &|x: u32| { x };

let o = Option::Some(3);

o.map(a); // trait bound `std::ops::FnOnce(u32) -> u32: std::ops::Fn<(u32,)>` is not satisfied
o.map(b); // trait bound `std::ops::FnMut(u32) -> u32: std::ops::Fn<(u32,)>` is not satisfied
o.map(c); // works
```

Shouldn't all of them, including `a` and `b`, implement `FnOnce` according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395/when-does-a-closure-implement-fn-fnmut-and-fnonce)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not calling `Option::map` with a `FnOnce` directly, but with a `&FnOnce`.

But if you look at the [implementors for `FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html#implementors), you'll notice that while `FnOnce` is implemented for `&Fn`, it is not implemented for `&FnOnce` or `&FnMut`.
To understand why, consider the following:

```
let a: &FnOnce(u32) -> u32 = &|x: u32| { v = x; x };
let b: &FnOnce(u32) -> u32 = a;

a(42); // would be allowed if `&FnOnce: FnOnce`, moves `a`
       // actually gives: 
       // error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
a(6);  // would not be allowed as `a` was moved
b(7);  // would be allowed if `&FnOnce: FnOnce`
       // oh no! this calls the function again!
```