# When should I add mut to closures?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = String::from("a");
    let closure = || {
        a.push_str("b");
    };

    closure();
}
```

This won't compile:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable local variable `closure` as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:7:5
  |
3 |     let closure = || {
  |         ------- consider changing this to `mut closure`
...
7 |     closure();
  |     ^^^^^^^ cannot borrow mutably
```

If I return `a` in the closure without adding `mut`, it can be compiled:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = String::from("a");
    let closure = || {
        a.push_str("b");
        a
    };

    closure();
}
```

This confuses me a lot. It seems like when I call `closure()`, `closure` will be borrowed if something is mutable inside it. Why won't it be borrowed when I return `a`?

Answer (score 30):

There are 3 function traits in Rust: `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce`. Going backward:

- `FnOnce` only guarantees that the value can be called once,
- `FnMut` only guarantees that the value can be called if it is mutable,
- `Fn` guarantees that the value can be called, multiple times, and without being mutable.

A closure will [automatically implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395/when-does-a-closure-implement-fn-fnmut-and-fnonce) those traits, depending on what it captures and how it uses it. By default, the compiler will pick the *least* restrictive trait; so favor `Fn` over `FnMut` and `FnMut` over `FnOnce`.

In your second case:

```
let mut a = String::from("a");
let closure = || {
    a.push_str("b");
    a
};
```

This closure requires being able to return `a`, which requires `FnOnce`. It moves `a` into the capture. If you tried to call your closure a second time, it would fail to compile. If you tried to access `a`, it would fail to compile too.

This is why `FnOnce` is a "last resort" implementation.

On the other hand your first case:

```
let mut a = String::from("a");
let closure = || {
    a.push_str("b");
};
```

At most requires a mutable reference to `a`, and therefore the capture occurs by mutable reference. Since it captures a mutable reference, the closure implements `FnMut`, and therefore can only be called if it is itself mutable.

If you remove `mut`, in front of `a`, the compiler will signal to you it needs to borrow `a` mutably.

The compiler does not require that `closure` itself be declared mutably until you attempt to call it; after all you could pass it by value to a function without calling it (yourself), in which case `mut` would be superfluous.

Comment: Regarding your latest paragraph. Would the function that receives the passed-by-value function mark the closure as `mut` in its signature?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg: It may, but wouldn't need to. This is because if you have ownership of something, you can always rebind it to a mutable binding. That is `let a = ...; let mut a = a;`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your prompt reply Sir!

Comment: Closures capturing variables can not be coerced to Fn, FnMut or FnOnce, so it is not possible to provide them as paramters to a function as of Rust 1.68