# Cannot move out of captured outer variable in an Fn closure

Tags: rust

```
fn make_adder(x: String) -> Box<Fn() -> String> {
    Box::new(|| x)
}

fn main() {
    make_adder(String::from("a"));
}
```

This results in this error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
 --> src/main.rs:2:17
  |
1 | fn make_adder(x: String) -> Box<Fn() -> String> {
  |               - captured outer variable
2 |     Box::new(|| x)
  |                 ^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
```

How can I make it correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I add mut to closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986734/when-should-i-add-mut-to-closures)

Comment: For people thinking about closing this as a dupe: There are similar questions like ["
Cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662098/cannot-move-out-of-captured-outer-variable-in-an-fn-closure) or ["How can I move a captured variable into a closure within a closure?
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521637/how-can-i-move-a-captured-variable-into-a-closure-within-a-closure), but both have examples far from *minimal*. I'd propose to keep this question as it has a nice small example.

Comment: Change `Fn` to `FnOnce`.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt a duplicate still serves as an example; the linked questions contain the answer.

Answer (score 19):

A closure which implements [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) **can be called multiple times** (the receiver parameter is `&self`, an immutable reference to the closure):

```
fn call_multiple_times<F: Fn(u8) -> i32>(f: F) {
    // Works! We can call the closure mutliple times
    let a = f(1);
    let b = f(27);
    let c = f(31);
}
```

This means that with your closure `Fn() -> String`, you could do this:

```
let s1 = adder();
let s2 = adder();
```

Now you would have **two `String`s although you only started with one! Magic?** You can of course get another string by cloning the original string, but we don't do that here. So it clearly can't work.

---

You can fix that in two ways. Either you don't need your closure to be called multiple times. In that case you can simply change `Fn` to [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) (a less demanding trait). An `FnOnce` closure can only be called ... well ... once. This works:

```
fn make_adder(x: String) -> Box<FnOnce() -> String> {
    Box::new(|| x)
}
```

On the other hand, maybe you want the closure to be called multiple times and always want to return a new clone of the string. You can do that like this:

```
fn make_adder(x: String) -> Box<Fn() -> String> {
    Box::new(move || x.clone())
}
```

Here we added a `.clone()` call (since in Rust, deep clones are never implicit!) and we added the `move` keyword. The latter is necessary to explicitly move the string `x` into the closure, not just borrow it.