# expected fn pointer, found closure

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a function that accumulates numbers provided by a supplier for a given range starting from zero:

```
fn accumulate<F>(size: usize, supplier: F) -> Successors<f64, fn(&f64) -> Option<f64>>
    where F: Fn(usize) -> f64 {
    let mut range = 0..size;
    successors(
        Some(0.0),
        |acc| range.next().map(|n| *acc + supplier(n)),
    )
}
```

The error message is:

```
114 |         |acc| range.next().map(|n| *acc + supplier(&config, n)),
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found closure
```

This is strange because the successors function expects a closure, namely `FnMut`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395/when-does-a-closure-implement-fn-fnmut-and-fnonce

Comment: `fn` is not the same as `Fn`. `Fn` is a callable trait, which closures can conform to. `fn` is a function pointer; closures cannot be converted to function pointers.

Comment: I understand that a closure cannot be coerced to a function pointer, but I see that the function I am calling actually accepts a closure. Then why does it complain that I am passing in a closure not a function pointer?

Comment: The return type says `fn(&f64)`.

Comment: tl;dr the duplicates: use `impl Fn(&f64) -> Option<f64>` (or one of the other options described, but `impl Trait` is probably what you want)

Comment: You probably actually need `FnMut` to allow the closure to mutate its environment, and you might need to add `move` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check the signature for your `accumulate` function: the return type is `Successors<f64, fn(&f64) -> Option<f64>>`, i.e., the successor is expecting the second generic parameter to be `fn(&f64) -> Option<f64>` - a `fn`.

Try changing that to `Fn(&f64) -> Option<f64>` - as per the comment from @ChrisJesterYoung.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to change it to Fn(&f64) -> Option<f64> or FnMut(&f64) -> Option<f64> but then I am getting this error: "cannot infer type for type parameter `F` declared on the function `accumulate`".