# Why closure writing to its context still implements traits FnOnce?

Tags: rust

I am confused. I have watched nearly all videos and official documentation on closures as well as a couple of unofficial, but still have difficulty predicting the behavior of the compiler.

Especially useful I've found [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395/when-does-a-closure-implement-fn-fnmut-and-fnonce) and [related article](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/05/finding-closure-in-rust/).

Particularly this:

```rust
  let mut b = "def".to_string();
  let closure_move_1 = move | mut a : String |
  {
     b.push( 'g' );
     a.push_str( &b );
     println!( "closureMove : {:?}", a );
     a
  };

  // try to uncomment
  // fn_once_1( closure_move_1 );
  // works
  // ? but why? routine write to its closure!

  // try to uncomment
  // fn_1( closure_move_1 );
  // ! this closure implements `FnMut`, not `Fn`
  // ? but why fn_once_1 works?

  // try to uncomment
  // fn_mut_1( closure_move_1 );
  // works as predicted
```

Here is a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=14fc961f100f66c7b911e078d22de997) with source code.
What did I miss?

Comment: In the first question you linked, it says: "All closures implement `FnOnce`: a closure that can't be called once doesn't deserve the name." This is the behavior you are observing. `FnOnce` implies that a closure can be called *at least* once, not only once.

Comment: This can be considered as a polymorphism, since `FnMut` and `Fn` types [implement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html#implementors) `FnOnce` both can be used as `FnOnce`, same [relation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/function.rs.html#242-249)  exists  between `Fn` and `FnMut`.