# How should I return an anonymous function from a parent function to generate a Closure?

Tags: rust, closures

I explain my question with this code snippet. Since main() it works as I expect. Now I want to move that to a function outside of main(). I have not found the syntax how the return should be done. The documentation seems to show many approaches, but I can't find the exact one.

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, Rust!");

    let mut _i = 0;
    let mut closure = || -> i32 {
        _i = _i + 1;
        _i
    };

    println!("closure returns: {}", closure());
    println!("closure returns: {}", closure());
    println!("closure returns: {}", closure());

    // OK, returns 1, 2, 3, ...

    // now i want to encapsulate this in a function, something like:
    let fn_closure = get_counter();

    println!("closure returns: {}", fn_closure()); 
    println!("closure returns: {}", fn_closure()); 
    println!("closure returns: {}", fn_closure()); 

    // expect: returns 1, 2, 3, ...
}

// try failed - how returns the closure?
fn get_counter() -> || -> i32 { //? 
    let mut _i = 1;
    let mut f = || -> i32 {
        _i = _i + 1;
        _i
    };
    f
}
```

In other words, I would like to reproduce this same example written in C# but in Rust

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Hello, C#!");

var closure = GetCounter();

Console.WriteLine("closure returns: {0}", closure());
Console.WriteLine("closure returns: {0}", closure());
Console.WriteLine("closure returns: {0}", closure());

// OK, output is 1 , 2 , 3, ...

static Func<int> GetCounter()
{
    int _i = 0;
    return () => ++_i;
}
```

P.S. Perhaps it is a very easy conceptual question, excuse me.

Comment: Note that the leading underscore is conventionally used for identifiers you **don't** use. So `let mut _i` should rather be `let mut i`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the return type `impl FnMut() -> i32`. This can be seen as shorthand for  [“a concrete type that implements this trait(`FnMut`)”](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.impl.html#). In other teams we can use the [*impl Trait* syntax in the return position to return a value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#returning-types-that-implement-traits) of some type that implements a trait. Quoting from the documentation.

> Closures and iterators create types that only the compiler knows or
> types that are very long to specify. The `impl Trait` syntax lets you
> concisely specify that a function returns some type that implements
> the Iterator trait without needing to write out a very long type.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, Rust!");

    let mut _i = 0;
    let mut closure = || -> i32 {
        _i = _i + 1;
        _i
    };

    println!("closure returns: {}", closure());
    println!("closure returns: {}", closure());
    println!("closure returns: {}", closure());


    let mut fn_closure = get_counter();

    println!("closure returns: {}", fn_closure()); 
    println!("closure returns: {}", fn_closure()); 
    println!("closure returns: {}", fn_closure()); 

}

fn get_counter() -> impl FnMut() -> i32 {  
    let mut _i = 1;
    let f = move || -> i32 {
        _i = _i + 1;
        _i
    };
    f
}
```

See also

- [When does a closure implement Fn, FnMut and FnOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395/when-does-a-closure-implement-fn-fnmut-and-fnonce)

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @AlexandraDanithAnsley Please note, when a question has been answered to their satisfaction, the asker is expected to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/627709) the best answer. Doing so marks the question as resolved for future visitors, and awards the volunteer who provided the answer with a token reputation reward.