# Cannot move out of X, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure

Tags: rust

I implemented a trait to share similar logic between my structs. This trait provides a `collect_responses` function, which takes vector of handlers and return vector of responses from the handlers. But after I applied this trait I got an errors like:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `input`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/lib.rs:16:30
   |
12 |         input: HandlerInput
   |         ----- captured outer variable
...
16 |             .map(|func| func(input))
   |                  ------------^^^^^-
   |                  |           |
   |                  |           move occurs because `input` has type `HandlerInput<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                  captured by this `FnMut` closure

error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `input`
```

This is my trait code:

```
pub trait Processor {
    fn process_input(input: HandlerInput) -> Result<Vec<HandlerOutput>, Error>;

    fn collect_responses(
        handlers: Vec<fn(HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerOutput, Error>>,
        input: HandlerInput
    ) -> Result<Vec<HandlerOutput>, Error> {
        let responses = handlers
            .iter()
            .map(|func| func(input))
            .filter(|r| match r {
                Ok(_) => true,
                _ => false,
            })
            .map(|r| r.unwrap())
            .collect::<Vec<HandlerOutput>>();

        return if responses.is_empty() {
            Err(
                Error::new(
                    ErrorKind::Other,
                    "No successful response"
                )
            )
        } else {
            Ok(responses)
        }
    }
}
```

This is [sandbox implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=31af477b1fb8ea805a6c80218b155759) in context of my real code.

Could somebody explain, why this issue happen and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fn(HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerOutput, Error>
```

This is almost certainly not the type you want, for multiple reasons. First, `fn` is a function pointer, i.e. a literal function written at the top level in your application. It can't be a closure or some other function-like thing. `fn` is almost exclusively used for interfacing with C, so you, at minimum, want [`Fn`, `FnMut`, or `FnOnce`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395/when-does-a-closure-implement-fn-fnmut-and-fnonce). See that link for more details on the difference. `FnOnce` won't suffice because you need to call it in a `map`, so I'm guessing you want `FnMut`, but read the difference between `FnMut` and `Fn` and determine for yourself which one you need.

Second, if you write

```
FnMut(HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerOutput, Error>
```

This is a function that takes a `HandlerInput` by value. It *moves* its argument and the caller can never use the argument again. So you certainly can't call it several times on the same `handler` in a `.map`, since the very first call moves the value and renders the variable `handler` unusable. If `HandlerInput` implements `Clone`, then you can write

```
.map(|func| func(input.clone())
```

But that's probably not what you want. Almost certainly, you want a reference here.

```
FnMut(&HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerOutput, Error>
FnMut(&mut HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerOutput, Error>
```

The first is a function which takes an immutable reference to a `HandlerInput`. It can read the `HandlerInput` but can't change, move, or drop it. If `HandlerInput` is a read-only data structure, then this is the best option.

The second is a function which takes a mutable reference. It can read and modify the `HandlerInput` but can't move or drop it. It also can't be safely used across threads. Use this if your handlers are intended to modify the input argument.

Comment: I'm almost certain that he wants `FnOnce` and `.into_iter()`, because he already has ownership of the `Vec`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=813976c2fc930200f3af52eefcf31d4c