# trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword when apply on vector of FnMut

Tags: rust

I replaced `fn(x) -> y` typing with `FnMut(x) -> y` according to my needs and according to what was suggested for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72548408/cannot-move-out-of-x-a-captured-variable-in-an-fnmut-closure). But I got another error:

> trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword

This is [minimal sandbox](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b8e2a9746bcc65b289334efbdad1b8b5) that reproduces the error.

I tried to investigate the issue. So, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650070/what-does-dyn-mean-in-a-type). After that I tried to add dyn. But since I got error that size in not known at compile time, I also tried to add `Box` to typing like:

```
-> vector<Box<dyn FnMut(HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerResponse, Error>>>
```

and after that tried to wrap handlers with `Box::new()`, but still have no success. I feel like I do something wrong.

Could somebody explain me how to fix this issue ? Maybe dyn not what I should use ? (I also tried to use impl instead, but this not helped)

Comment: `FnMut` -> `dyn FnMut` -> `Box<dyn FnMut>` is the correct set of changes to get you on your way. You should post your version with that and then show your problems. I see you've only partially applied other suggestions from your last post (changed the function type to `FnMut(&mut HandlerInput)` but did not change your `handler1`, `handler2`, etc functions)

Comment: Besides that, your playground is far from being minimal. If you want to locate errors, you really have to make a **small** example where the error occurs.

Comment: @kmdreko thank you for comment, could you please look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549399/expected-a-fnmutx-closure-found-dyn-forr-s-fnmutr-mut-xs ?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Here is a [fixed version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=25c3f49a4f30872bed38236868ae74d3) of your example with some minor refactoring to improve safety/usability. However it likely still won't work because `handle_read` can't tell where one packet ends and the next begins. It just returns whatever data has been buffered by the OS. You may want to consider something like prefixing packets with their lengths so you can distinguish between them.

Comment: @Locke thank you very much ! If you add your comment as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a huge difference between `fn(x) -> y` and `FnMut(x) -> y`: the former is a type (basically, it's a pointer to a function), while the second is a [trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html). This means that you can't switch the one for the other. Fortunately, there is a way (actually, multiple ways) to tell Rust that you want to accept any type that implements a given trait. One of these is trait objects, whose syntax is `dyn Trait` where `Trait` is a trait.

#### Trait objects

Traits objects use dynamic dispatch, which means that Rust allows any type that implements a given trait `Trait` to be passed where a `dyn Trait` was expected, and the information about where the different methods are found for a given value of type `dyn Trait` is provided by runtime information (ie. that value also has a little table included providing that information). This means that, for instance, Rust cannot know the size of `dyn Trait` at compile time, simply because it could be any value, as long as its type implements `Trait`. For this reason, you need to allocate it on the heap, and pass a pointer to the allocated data instead. This is the job of `Box`.

The solution is therefore to replace any occurence of `Trait` as a type declaration with `Box<dyn Trait>` (in your case, `Box<dyn FnMut(HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerResponse, Error>>>`) and make the appropriate changes (ie. (un)box your closures).