# expected a `FnMut<(X<'_>,)>` closure, found `dyn for<'r, 's> FnMut(&'r mut X<'s>) -> Result<Y, std::io::Error>`

Tags: rust

I implemented a trait to share similar logic between my structs. This trait provides a `collect_responses` function, which takes vector of handlers and return vector of responses from the handlers. I cannot compile my code because I got an error:

```
error[E0277]: expected a `FnMut<(HandlerInput<'_>,)>` closure, found `dyn for<'r, 's> FnMut(&'r 
mut HandlerInput<'s>) -> Result<HandlerOutput, std::io::Error>`
   --> src/lib.rs:146:18
    |
146 |             self.process(handler, vec![]);
    |                  ^^^^^^^ expected an `FnMut<(HandlerInput<'_>,)>` closure, found `dyn for<'r, 's> FnMut(&'r mut HandlerInput<'s>) -> Result<HandlerOutput, std::io::Error>`
    |
    = help: the trait `FnMut<(HandlerInput<'_>,)>` is not implemented for `dyn for<'r, 's> 
    FnMut(&'r mut HandlerInput<'s>) -> Result<HandlerOutput, std::io::Error>`
    = note: expected a closure with arguments `(&mut HandlerInput<'_>,)`
           found a closure with arguments `(HandlerInput<'_>,)`
    = note: required because of the requirement
```

This is [sandbox example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fef9e7b9a5efad0a69f46cdc5305be4a) in context of my real code.

This is trait code:

```
pub trait Processor {
    fn process_input(input: HandlerInput) -> Result<Vec<HandlerOutput>, Error>;

    fn collect_responses(
        handlers: Vec<Box<dyn FnMut(&mut HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerOutput, Error>>>,
        input: HandlerInput
    ) -> Result<Vec<HandlerOutput>, Error> {
        let responses = handlers
            .iter()
            .map(|func| func(&mut input))
            .filter(|r| match r {
                Ok(_) => true,
                _ => false,
            })
            .map(|r| r.unwrap())
            .collect::<Vec<HandlerOutput>>();

        return if responses.is_empty() {
            Err(
                Error::new(
                    ErrorKind::Other,
                    "No successful response"
                )
            )
        } else {
            Ok(responses)
        }
    }
}
```

This is place in code where I got an error:

```
fn process<F>(&mut self, handler: F, data: Vec<u8>)
    where
        F: FnMut(HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerOutput, Error>
{
    let response: Result<HandlerOutput, Error> = handler(HandlerInput {
        session: &mut self.session,
        data: Some(data),
    });

    match response.unwrap() {
        HandlerOutput::Data(result) => {
            self.handle_write(result).unwrap();
        },
        HandlerOutput::ConnectionRequest(host, port) => {
            self.connect(&host[..], port);
        },
        HandlerOutput::Void => {},
    }
}
```

Could you please explain me how can I pass the handler correctly to the `self.process` ?

**UPDATED:** this is how I call `process` function:

```
let handlers = AuthProcessor::init();
for handler in handlers {
    self.process(handler, vec![]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is pointing you right to the error.  You have a boxed closure of the basic type:

```
FnMut(&mut HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerOutput, Error>
```

But you're trying to give it to a function that wants:

```
FnMut(HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerOutput, Error>
```

The arguments don't match.  You need to change one of them to match the other.