# Why FnMut closures consume captured variables?

Tags: rust, closures, move-semantics

The Iterator trait's method `any` takes a parameter implementing FnMut trait.

Here's the definiton

```
#[inline]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
fn any<F>(&mut self, f: F) -> bool
where
    Self: Sized,
    F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> bool,
{
    #[inline]
    fn check<T>(mut f: impl FnMut(T) -> bool) -> impl FnMut((), T) -> ControlFlow<()> {
        move |(), x| {
            if f(x) { ControlFlow::BREAK } else { ControlFlow::CONTINUE }
        }
    }
    self.try_fold((), check(f)) == ControlFlow::BREAK
}
```

---

I think the rule of FnMut is: The closure captures variables by mutable reference.

---

But the following code goes wrong because of "use of moved value: `rust`".

This means the variable `rust` has been moved into the closure, which has conflicts with the rule of FnMut trait.

```
// Situation 1
let rust = String::from("rust");
let list: Vec<String> = vec![String::from("rust")];
list.into_iter().any(move |s| s == rust);
dbg!(rust); // error here
```

However, the following code is also refused by the compiler due to the rule of FnMut trait.

```
// Situation 2
let rust = String::from("rust");
let list: Vec<String> = vec![String::from("rust")];
list.into_iter().any(move |s| {
    let temp = rust; // error here
    s == temp
});
```

---

So my question is, why there are different behaviors about the FnMut trait between these two situations?

I think the second situation is easy to understand. But why in the first situation, the captured variable will be consumed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does a closure implement Fn, FnMut and FnOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395/when-does-a-closure-implement-fn-fnmut-and-fnonce)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I don't think that is a duplicate of this, though it overlaps considerably.

Comment: @PeterHall The OP misunderstood what `FnMut` is, so I think it's an appropriate duplicate. Of course you're free to think otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `FnMut`, it's `move`. The `move` keyword in `move |s|` causes [captured variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/closures/capture.html) to be moved into the closure. Leave it off to use the default capture mode, by reference:

```
let rust = String::from("rust");
let list: Vec<String> = vec![String::from("rust")];
list.into_iter().any(|s| s == rust);
dbg!(rust);
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8941bc3d636fbd80017dafba5f9f799)</sup>

Comment: I know. But the `any` takes FnMut. I think it's not allowed to pass FnOnce as the parameter.

Comment: @Autumnal_Joy That's sort of right. All closures are `FnOnce`, but some are _also_ `FnMut`, and some of those are also `Fn`. The closure you provided in the second example is _only_ `FnOnce`, so cannot be used as an argument that requires an `FnMut`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now understand why I am wrong. I mistakenly thought of “move” and “FnOnce” as the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The variable has been moved into the closure because you used the `move` keyword. It has nothing to do with it being a `FnMut`.

The second code block produces an error because the closure might be called multiple times (since it's constrained to be `FnMut`), but the line `let temp = rust;` moves that variable again, into a variable that is dropped within the function body. This means that the environment of the closure would be invalid if it was ever called again. All functions and closures implement `FnOnce`, but this one can *only* implement `FnOnce` - i.e. it cannot implement `Fn` or `FnMut`.

Comment: Do you mean "the capture‘s behavior" and "the use of captured variables" are not the same thing, and the "Fn*" trait is associated with the latter one?

Comment: Yes. Closures usually capture by reference. The `move` keyword changes that behaviour to make them capture by value. This is orthogonal to the behaviour implied by the specific `Fn*` traits.

Comment: Thanks! I used to think the rule of FnMut is: The closure captures variables by mutable reference, but I was wrong. It should be: The closure uses variables by mutable reference.

Comment: Yes that's right. In a `move FnMut` it could also still mutate the variables in its environment - the difference is that it owns them.