# Understanding Iter with FnMut

Tags: rust

Since [Iter's "all" fn takes type FnMut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) is it possible to update the element while checking for condition and short circuiting? Though I understand it is not supposed to, but what prevents it from updating the value?

```
fn main() {
   let a = ["as", "zz"];

    let mut iter = a.iter();
    iter.all(|& (mut x)| {x = "cc"; true});

    for z in a.iter(){
        println!("{z}");
    }
}
```

Above prints

```
as
zz
```

In above case why setting "x = cc" not work?
Or Alternatively why does Iter "all" method takes F of type FnMut and not Fn when it is not supposed to mutate but only validate for condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x = "cc"` does not change the value referred by `x`, instead it  changes the reference itself (i.e. it makes it refer to another value), as evidenced by this example:

```
fn main() {
   let a = ["as", "zz"];

    let mut iter = a.iter();
    iter.all(|&(mut x)| {
        println!("before: {:?}", x as *const _);
        x = "cc";
        println!("after: {:?}", x as *const _); 
        true});

    for z in a.iter(){
        println!("{z}");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=741ae35f04be7019a3d6d5033d4ee921)

Note that this has nothing to do with the fact that the closure is `FnMut`, which only means that it may change any captured values as in:

```
fn main() {
   let a = ["as", "zz"];

    let mut count = 0;
    let mut iter = a.iter();
    iter.all(|&_x| {
        count += 1;    // This is possible because the closure is `FnMut`
        true});
    println!("Count: {count}");
    
    for z in a.iter(){
        println!("{z}");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2b65aad49664167dfa2bcaecd4c7f3e)

Answer (score 4):

Do not be mistaken! A function implementing [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) means that it captures a receiving context mutably. It does *not mean* that its items may be modified from its original source.

```rust
let mut k = 0;
assert_eq!((10..15)..all(|x| {
    k += 1;
    x > k
}), true);
```

Given

```
let mut iter = a.iter();
```

we have an iterator the items of which are references to elements in vector `a`. And these references are immutable. In order to have an iterator which allows you to mutate the items in a vector, use `iter_mut`.

```
let iter = a.mut_iter();
iter.all(|x| { *x = "cc"; true});

for z in a.iter(){
    println!("{z}");
}
```

This would still not require `FnMut` in particular, since it does not capture any context other than the items iterated on. The adaptor `all` (and many other iterator adaptors) were designed to constrain to `FnMut` so that the closures passed as their first parameter are allowed to keep and manipulate some external state for whichever logic they intend to do. Since the closure is called sequentially in the same thread, this is always memory safe.

See also:

- [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587698/whats-the-difference-between-placing-mut-before-a-variable-name-and-after-the)
- [When does a closure implement Fn, FnMut and FnOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395/when-does-a-closure-implement-fn-fnmut-and-fnonce)