# what does it mean for FnMut to take an immutable reference?

Tags: rust

```
pub fn sort_by_key<K, F>(&mut self, mut f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&T) -> K,
    K: Ord,
{
    merge_sort(self, |a, b| f(a).lt(&f(b)));
}
```

Here `FnMut` takes an immutable reference `&T`, what does it mean?

Isn't `FnMut` supposed to take a mutable reference `&mut T`?

Comment: `FnMut` takes a mutable reference *to the captured variables*, but it can take any type as argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a `FnMut` means this function *may* use a mutable reference to a caputred variable. For example, take [this function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html#calling-a-mutably-capturing-closure):

```
let mut x = 5;
{
    let mut square_x = || x *= x;
    square_x();
}
assert_eq!(x, 25);
```

This function takes no arguments. Certainly no immutable arguments. Yet it's considered a `FnMut` because it captures the mutable reference to `x` and mutates. it.

Note that `Fn` is a subtype of `FnMut`. Thus, any function that takes a `FnMut` can also be passed a function that does not mutate state. In this case, `|a, b| f(a).lt(&f(b))` is just a `Fn`. It can be called multiple times and mutates no state. But any `Fn` is also a valid `FnMut` and any `FnMut` or `Fn` is also a valid `FnOnce`.

This does mean `Fn` can take a mutable reference as a parameter, so this is valid:

```rs
let b:Box<dyn Fn(&mut u8)->()> = Box::new(|a|*a+=1);
```

This function uses a mutable reference yet it's a `Fn` not a `FnMut` since it doesn't capture any variables.

[See also this question for a lot more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395/when-does-a-closure-implement-fn-fnmut-and-fnonce)